# How to completely disable Windows 10's low storage notification?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I use a PCIE Nand Drive as readyboost to improve my Windows 10's performance (and it does improve the performance drastically). The trouble is Windows recognize it as an internal drive instead of a portable drive, and therefore will pop out low storage notification.

I have follow the instruction found here: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1264602-windows-10-disable-the-low-disk-space-warning/

Basically what I did is:

```
LowDiskMinimumMBytes DWORD 0 --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gather

BackOffLowDiskThresholdMB DWORD 0 --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager

NoLowDiskSpaceChecks DWORD 1 --> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

And restarted.

Unfortunately it does not stop the notification.

Comment: NoLowDiskSpaceChecks should be a 1

Comment: @CoscoTech my mistake when editing this question, it was set to 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something people would struggle with. Microsoft should probably update the guide to disable this notification for Windows 10.

```
LowDiskMinimumMBytes DWORD 0 --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gather

BackOffLowDiskThresholdMB DWORD 0 --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager
```

These two modification won't do anything. It's for the Windows Search, not the system. Don't mess around with them. You cannot change the ownership bad to TrustedInstaller. If you have already, don't panic, you won't have much trouble if you use users who have administrator privilege and don't need to modify these settings with users from other groups.

No here is the trick. Instead of in current user, Microsoft moved the setting entirely to local machine. So you really should just:

```
NoLowDiskSpaceChecks DWORD 1 --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

Someone from Microsoft should look into editing this page so users don't get confused: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555622